# Browser events default action - Is there a spec for it?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, specifications, preventdefault

Some [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) has default action. For example - clicking on a checkbox will check/uncheck it. This can be prevented by the [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method.

While looking for the `errorEvent` default action, I could not find any documentation or specs about events default action - not only for `errorEvent`, but for ANY event. According to the [DOM spec - Constructing events scetion](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event)

> As of the time of this writing Web IDL does not yet define any default behavior; see whatwg/webidl#135.

Beyond that, I couldn't find any clear or update-to-date information regarding any progress on such spec.
Is it possible such spec still doesn't finalize, so the default actions can be different for different browsers? or am I missing something?

UPDATE:

My question wasn't clear enough - clearly, an event can have different default actions for different context (e.g. a click event for a checkbox-input will have a different default action than a click event on a text-input)

Thanks to @kaiido's elaborated answer I've found the spec I was looking for (which is specifically for DOM UI events) - [UI Events section 4.1 List of Event Types](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-types-list)

Comment: The HTML5 specification does describe what events should do, in the context of the definitions of particular element semantics.

Comment: I'm referring specifically to event default actions. I could not find any spec of such thing. Is it exist? Can you please provide a link for such spec?

Comment: Each HTML element definition in the spec describes what the browser should do when an event of a given type is triggered.

Comment: Also what you're looking for does not make sense. A "click" event on a `<div>` has no default action, while a "click" on a radio button does. A radio button default action is different than a checkbox default action and than a `<select>` default action.

Comment: see the "Update" section on my question

Answer (score 4):

There is no real "default action" per Event type, so no, you wont find a default action for "click" Events, nor for "error" Events.
What happens is that in various places, it is defined that after an event (note the lower-case "e"), some *things* should occur, among which, an Event may be dispatched, and then possibly something else, based on the [canceled flag](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#canceled-flag) of the Event that got dispatched.

If you like to look at specs, then the [DOM specifications](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org) define that when [an event is being dispatched](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dispatching-events), the User Agent must check the *canceled flag* of the dispatched Event, and if it's still unset, then it must run the [activation behavior](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#eventtarget-activation-behavior) of the target (step 11.1).
This *activation behavior* is what other specs will define and which thus correspond to the "default behavior" you are looking for.
Note that [UI Events](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-flow-default-cancel) also goes into details with different terms to describe this same behavior.

Also, many specs may have their own ways of defining this behavior, for instance [WebGL's contextlost](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.15.2) event defines directly what should happen in the case the event has been canceled without defining an *activation behavior*, which wouldn't mean much on a WebGL context.

Thus, there isn't a single place where all such "preventable" actions are defined. Every specification may define many of these.
Browser's interoperability is preserved because they follow every specs that do define these.

Might be interesting to note though that your checkbox example is actually quite an outsider, since, for weird historical reasons, the default action of switching the `.checked` property is done before dispatching the Event, and after the Event has been dispatched it is being restored to the initial state if the event has been canceled.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborated answer!
After looking at the UIEvent spec you've mentioned, I saw that surprisingly,  there is a list for default action per event (under some assumptions). See section 4.1  - "List of event Types" - default action column 
 https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-types-list

Comment: @yuval.bl yes, good spot but note that this only concerns UI trusted events, and is far from being an exhaustive list.

Comment: understood, thanks.